# I need to get IPv4 address and memory with powershell with Get-SCVirtualMachine

Tags: powershell

The following gets me the name and IPv4 address but not the memory and status of all virtual machines

`Get-SCVirtualMachine | Get-SCVirtualNetworkAdapter | select name,ipv4Addresses, memory, status`

The Powershell command below gets me the name, memory, and status off all virtual machines

`Get-SCVirtualMachine | ft  IPv4Addresses, name, memory, status`

How do I get both in the same table with all the information present?

`Get-SCVirtualMachine | Get-SCVirtualNetworkAdapter | ft IPv4Addresses, name, memory, status`

Do I need to use the `-sc` commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could do this:

```
Get-SCVirtualMachine | ForEach-Object {
    $IPv4 = ($_ | Get-SCVirtualNetworkAdapter).ipv4Addresses
    $_ | Select-Object *,@{N='ipv4Addresses';E={$IPv4}}
}
```

This gets all the Virtual Machines with the `Get-SCVirtualMachine` cmdlet, and then loops through each one and gets the IPv4 address.

Then we use the `Select-Object` cmdlet to return all the properties of the Virtual Machine (by using `*`) along with creating an additional property using a technique called [Calculated Properties](https://thomasrayner.ca/calculated-properties-in-powershell/) that adds the IPv4 Address to the final object collection.